# Sql server 2005 linked server to 2008 error A severe error occurred on the current command

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql, linked-server

I am able to query few tables on the linked server but few tables are giving me this error.

```
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was ableto solve this by installing SQL SERVER 2005 SP3 Hot Fix.

It is important to see if you not only have latest sql server updated but also the hotfixes.